# Docker Compose can't start container process

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use a windows laptop
This is the error

> ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "flask": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
>
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Below is the dockerfile

```
#syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.7-alpine

WORKDIR /code .
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5001
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "-m", "Flask", "run"]
```

Everything concerning the code is here https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

Comment: That error message doesn't match your Dockerfile: you're never actually trying to run the `flask` command anywhere in your `Dockerfile`. Can you update your question to include all the information necessary to reproduce this problem? What does your `docker run` command line look like? What does your `requirements.txt` file look like?

Comment: From the error message, "Flask" is not found in your container OS path. may check your requirements.txt. Try running this application on your machine, is it working normally?

Comment: maybe try "Flask" as "flask". being linux I guess it is case sensitive